# Fastest splitter?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax, sorting

Consider some dataset

```
N1 = 13;
N2 = 130*10^3;
N3 = 2*10^4;
tabtest = 
  Join[Join[RandomReal[{0, 3}, {N1, 4}], Table[{1.}, N1], 2], 
   Join[RandomReal[{0, 3}, {N2, 4}], Table[{2.}, N2], 2], 
   Join[RandomReal[{0, 3}, {N3, 4}], Table[{7.}, N3], 2]];
```

I need to get a list of lists with the same last element. The obvious one is

```
SplitBy[tabtest,Last];
```

However, it is relatively slow, taking 0.15 s on my machine. I made another code:

```
PhaseSpaceSplitter[phasespace_] := 
 Module[{grouped, lengths, positions, ranges, pso, pdgs},
  pdgs = phasespace[[All, -1]];
  If[Length[Union[pdgs]] != 1,
   (*Grouping consecutive identical elements*)
   grouped = Split[pdgs];
   (*Calculating the lengths of each group*)
   lengths = Length /@ grouped;
   (*Generating the start positions*)
   positions = Accumulate[Prepend[lengths, 0]];
   (*Forming ranges*)
   ranges = 
    Transpose[{Most[positions] + 1, Most[positions] + lengths}];
   pso = Take[phasespace, {#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ ranges
   ,
   pso = {phasespace};
   ];
  pso
  ]

splitted1 = SplitBy[tabtest, Last]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
splitted2 = PhaseSpaceSplitter[tabtest]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
splitted1 == splitted2
```

> 0.188216

> 0.0133451

> True

I am okay with how fast the last approach works. However, the speed gain is lost once I apply `RandomSample` on tabtest:

```
tabtest=tabtest//RandomSample;
splitted1 = SplitBy[tabtest, Last]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
splitted2 = PhaseSpaceSplitter[tabtest]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
splitted1 == splitted2
```

> 0.152886
>
> 0.243063
>
> True

How to make efficient code that makes the list of lists?

P.S. I cannot first make the backward sorting `SortBy[tabtest,#[[1]]&]` since `tabtest` is a set of columns of another table, and the ordering is important.

Comment: I am not sure why you think the obvious answer is `SplitBy`. You want to gather items by their last element, so the natural command would be ```GatherBy[tabtest, Last]```, which also happens to be 3-4x faster than `SplitBy`, and gives the same result here (```GatherBy[tabtest, Last] == SplitBy[tabtest, Last]``` returns True).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PositionIndex[ ] seems to take half of the time of GatherBy[ ]. I use the the test case provided, but evaluate the time with GatherBy[ ], after the comment by MarcoB:

```
splitGB = GatherBy[tabtest, Last]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
0.0653971

split[list_] := Module[{positions},
  positions = PositionIndex[list[[All, -1]]];
  Table[list[[positions[[i]]]], {i, Length[positions]}]
]

splitN = split[tabtest]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
0.0361735
```

Ordering is not important:

```
tab2 = RandomSample[tabtest];
splitM = split[tab2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
0.0342582

splitByM = GatherBy[tab2, Last]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
0.0616525

splitM == splitByM
True
```

May be you do not need the partitioned list of values. Using the list of position indexes may be enough, and will avoid doubling the storage required for the data.